# How to coerce vector of functions to character vector of the respective function names?

Tags: r

I found lots of examples coercing a single function into a length-1 character vector of its name. I'm trying to be able to do it for a vector/list of functions and I can't quite get it to work. See below code:

```
# singular working example
as.character(bquote(mean))
  [1] "mean"
# other singular example
deparse(substitute(mean))
  [1] "mean"
# my vector of functions
funsVector <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR)
# failure 1
sapply(funsList, bquote)
  [[1]]
  X[[i]]

  [[2]]
  X[[i]]

  [[3]]
  X[[i]]

  [[4]]
  X[[i]]

  [[5]]
  X[[i]]
# failure 2
sapply(funsList, function(x) deparse(substitute(x)))
  [1] "X[[i]]" "X[[i]]" "X[[i]]" "X[[i]]" "X[[i]]"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems that the functions "lose" their original names.  For instance, if I make the call `funsVector[1](1,2,3)`, then the name of this function actually is `funsVector[1]`, and not `mean()`.

Comment: I think you're going to have to change the way you're making the list to start with, probably so it ends up having `names()`

Comment: What you have there in the list are copies of the functions, not the original functions. Either create names for the list or just put only the function names in the list and use `getFunction` when you need to use the function.